# Transfering git branch to another computer and tracking correct branch

Tags: git

So I think I know how to do this but am not sure!

There is a project for which I have branch I've been working on to make a website responsive for mobile.  I set the branch up to track the `origin/prod` and now I've changed my computer and need to pull that branch down so I can continue to work on it from my new development environment.

When I created the branch on my old PC I ran:

```
$ git checkout -b rwd-theme origin/prod
```

When I check the remote branch with:

```
$ git branch -av
remotes/origin/rwd-theme             d6ea17d themeing header
```

Now I think on my new computer I need to run this command:

```
$ git checkout -b rwd-theme origin/rwd-theme
```

Is this correct?  Will it still track the origin/prod on my new local environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you already have cloned the repository from your remote repository to your local new machine everything is there.

```
git checkout -b rwd-theme origin/prod
```

This command will create a new branch called `rwd-theme` from `prod` branch where the `HEAD` of your `rwd-theme` will be same as origin `prod` branch and additionally will switch to `rwd-theme`.

Now you're planning to run the below command.

```
git checkout -b rwd-theme origin/rwd-theme
```

As you have already cloned the repository on your new local machine all you have to do is just run,

```
git checkout rwd-theme
```

You can also run `git checkout -b rwd-theme origin/rwd-theme` to switch to `rwd-theme` branch which will automatically associate the remote branch with local branch `rwd-theme`.

Optionally you can run `git remote show origin` to get more insight into what branches are being tracked with remote branches and other information such as which branches are configured for `git pull` and `push`.

If you want to specifically set `rwd-theme` to its remote branch, you can easily set it with

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/rwd-theme
```